# How to call async task with two url

Tags: java, android

I need to call asynctask with different urls. i have two button, they do a http post to server with different urls, now i can call asynctask with one url but how can i call the same function with different urls .. mean button 1 download url number 1 and button 2 download url number 2

```
   class DownloadFont extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainAc.this);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setMessage("download"));
            progressDialog.setTitle("wait"));

            progressDialog.show();

        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setMax(100);
            progressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
            String info_download = "";
            if (progress[0] > 99) {

               download = (getResources().getString("dff));

            } else {

                download = (getResources().getString(R.string.download)) + progress[0] + "%";
            }
            progressDialog.setMessage(download);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            if (result) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.done), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            Boolean flag = false;

            try {

                URL url = new URL("www.test_sweb.com/new.mp3");

                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();
```

Comment: When calling Asynctask `new DownloadFont().execute(url)` in doInBackground `URL url = new URL(args[0]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the doInBackground:

```
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg) {
        Boolean flag = false;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(arg[0]);

            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();
```

While in your activity or where you want to start the task(onClick):

```
string URL = "www.test_sweb.com/new.mp3";//Or the url you need
new DownloadFont().execute(URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

on the button click listner method you can put the url you want to execute in a string that you can send to doInBackground(String.. arg0) method:

```
DownloadFont.execute(yourview.getText(), URL_YOU_WANT_TO_EXEC);
```

and in your code get the url:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
URL_YOU_WANT_TO_EXEC = arg0[0];
.
.
.
}
```